# How to parse a html page, vb.net form

Tags: html, vb.net, winforms, parsing, webbrowser-control

how can I parse this html code:

```
<a href="http://member.20dollars2surf.com/points.php" class="bl" style="text-decoration:none">163 Punti</a><
```

I want to parse "163 Punti". I've tried to search on google but I didn't found nothing..
Someone could help me? Thanx

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hi, exist a solution only using outer text or other method? i know this library, but I never understood how to use it. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

The element doesn't have an `ID`. So you can't get the element by using `GetElementById` method (which is the surest way to identify an element). However you can use other methods.

```
    Dim allLinks As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A")
    For Each link As HtmlElement In allLinks
        If link.GetAttribute("href") = "http://member.20dollars2surf.com/points.php" Then
            Dim linkText As String = link.InnerHtml
            MessageBox.Show(linkText)
        End If
    Next
```

The above code will work properly only if there is only one link on the page with that URL. Otherwise you will need to further customize this code.

Comment: Hi, thanx!| unfortunately it doesn't work...  the error> http://i.imgur.com/5XkRIqs.png

Comment: There is only one link on the page with that URL

Comment: The markup shown in there is the rendered markup, not the actual source. Probably the relative path is specified in that link href. Try with replacing that URL in the above code with just `points.php` or `/points.php`